# An alternative to <div>

Tags: html, css

I am currently making a program, that converts an image into a "website". It's simply taking the pixels and gets their color and position, and then converts it into a div.

The problem is, that my browser (Google Chrome) crashes, when there are too many divs. I also have implemented quality, which basically means that the programm takes every n'th pixel and converts it. With a quality of 40 my program creates about 600 divs, and Chrome can't handle even this.

Is there an alternative to divs? I already tried canvas, but I couldn't really set their position. If you know how to set the position of a canvas, or know a good alternative to div, I'd be very thankful.

Comment: Why would the type of element, div vs anything, make a difference?

Comment: What makes you think replacing `<div>` with, for example, `<section>` will suddenly allow Chrome to breath again?

Comment: I doubt google chrome can't handle 600 `<div />`s. Also I totally don't see a point of such excercise. Maybe if you explain what are you trying to achieve people will be more likely to suggest something. Background image with `<area />` / `<map />` may fit

Comment: Why you couldn't set their position using ctx.rect(x, y, width, height) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the HTML5 Canvas, probably it would be even easier.You just need all the coordinates and colors to paint the desired amount of pixels.

Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API
for more information and documentation about Canvas

Even you can directly paint an image into the canvas if you don't want to the the pixel paint, just like this:

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
var img=document.getElementById("scream");
ctx.drawImage(img,10,10);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Oh thank you very much. I totally forgot one could draw into the canvas. Well that's embarassing. I'm not that familiar with HTML, I just wanted to make this program for fun. It works now, thank you ^^